# Replace HTML character entities in a string

Tags: c#, html, .net-3.5

I would like to take a string containing HTML character entities such as `&nbsp;`, etc. and replace them with the literal string characters. Does C# come with a library that has all the HTML character entities in which I could use to parse/replace characters in my strings?

List of HTML character entities: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using the [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) method of the HttpUtility class.

Comment: If you are using .Net framework 4+  you may prefer WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Comment: *"[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)"*, not *".Net"*.